# How to send extra results from a python generator to a consumer function?

Tags: python, generator

I have a library function (that I cannot change) that takes as input an iterator providing a certain type of objects. I implemented this input as a generator that parses text and yields portions of it. I would like to be able to take into account other information found during the text parsing.

The comments in the following example give an idea of what I would like to do:

```
the_text = """1:-
3:-
2:+
4:-
6:+
2:-
4:-
5:+
6:-
7:+"""

def extract_ints(text):
    for line in text.split("\n"):
        fields = line.split(":")
        #<send fields[1] to my_consumer_function>
        yield fields[0]

# Cannot modify this one (actually loaded from library)
def double_ints(num_source):
    """Only wants numbers."""
    for num in num_source:
        yield 2 * int(num)

def my_consumer_function(text):
    for value in double_ints(extract_ints(text)):
        #<receive sign from extract_ints>
        #if sign == "-":
        #    value *= -1
        print(value)

my_consumer_function(the_text)
```

How could I proceed to send this information from my generator to my consumer function along with the output of the unmodifiable library function?

Comment: you need to use this double_ints? can't you just call a map to do so?

Comment: This is just an example. I'm actually dealing with some bioinformatics analysis task, but I preferred to use a simple example.

Comment: Can you store the signs in a different array and then use enumerate to get the right index and access it from my_consumer_function?

Comment: Or maybe dynamically decorate the function to do what you want?

Comment: Storing the signs somewhere might be an idea, but I guess I would have to use a lot of `append`, which might slow down the code, and this would use space, which defeats the purpose of using iterators.
I don't see very clearly what you mean by "dynamically decorate".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder what's the best way, but here's one way:

```
from itertools import imap, izip, tee
from operator import itemgetter

def extract_ints(text):
    for line in text.split("\n"):
        fields = line.split(":")
        yield fields[0], fields[1]

def my_consumer_function(text):      
    it1, it2 = tee(extract_ints(text))
    it1 = double_ints(imap(itemgetter(0), it1))
    it2 = imap(itemgetter(1), it2)
    for value, sign in izip(it1, it2):
        if sign == "-":
            value *= -1
        print(value)
```

For Python 3 use regular `map` and `zip`.

Comment: I suspected something could be done using `tee`, but I still hadn't used it so far. Thanks.